# Probability problem about antenna coordination and interfering channel

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'v been solving some probability problems to get ready for my exam when I faced this. I blocked at point [5] and I dont't know how to keep on, can someone help me?
 
Consider a system where two entities *A* and *B* allocate elements in their own vectors of *N* elements, numbered from 1 to *N*. We say that there is interference on element *j* if it is allocated in both *A* and *B*’s vectors. Assume that each entity allocates its elements at random, and independently, and call *n*<sub>*A*</sub> and *n*<sub>*B*</sub> the number of elements allocated by each entity, 0$\le$*n*<sub>*X*</sub>$\le$N.
[1] Compute the probability that the allocation of *A* includes element 1.
[2] Compute the probability that the allocation of *A* includes element *j*.
[3] Compute the probability that there is interference on element *j*.
[4] Compute *L*,*U* , i.e., the minimum and maximum number of interfering elements among all possible allocations.
[5] Compute the probability that the allocations of *A* and *B* have exactly *k* interfering elements, for a generic *k*, *L*$\le$*k*$\le$*U*.
[6] Assume that *n*<sub>*A*</sub> = *n*<sub>*B*</sub> = *n*. Compute the probability that the two allocations are completely overlapping.

Comment: Lots of imperatives, no question.

Comment: Hint: Suppose there is an urn with $N$ balls, of which $n_A$ are black.  If you draw $n_B$ balls from the urn (without replacement), what is the probability that you have drawn exactly $k$ black balls?